# git: Cherry picking from one fork to another fork

Tags: git, github

I have forked a git repo, and created a PR. Another person from my team then uses this PR to make more changes, and created a PR on a fork of his own.

Is is possible to cherry pick from his PR to my PR, as they are in different forks now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats possible.

Add a new remote from the other fork with following command:

```
git remote add FORK https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
git fetch FORK
```

The cherry-pick will work like always.

with that you can pull from that repository (if you have read permissions) and you can cherry-pick the changes to your fork PR.

note that this makes the second Pull Request redundant.